# How to resolve mobile data connection(2G/3G/EDGE/GPRS) lost in android after coming out from wifi programatically?

Tags: android

I need a fix for this strange problem appearing in android. Sometimes I notice that even I have full cellular network, data network is lost.(Not able to connect to internet although have all set properly). This possibly occurs after I leave wifi. A quick fix to make it working is toggle 2G/3G option in settings --> Mobile Networks, which probably clears the network stack and makes it all working.
But for my application, which requires always to be connected to internet, I need a fix programatically. I cannot toggle that from code ? Or can I ?

I read and tried a fix by rewriting APN settings, but that do not solve the issue entirely, as we move out from wifi connectivity. 
Do anyone have any fix for this from code ?

Comment: No solution ? There needs to be some way around. I found only solution is to toggle 2G/3G manually. This is no way useful as it requires user attention and response. I think its case with all androids and generally happens when device sleeps a long time. So will holding a partial wake lock solve it completely ? But then this is useless for keeping device always on. So also is the case for accelerometer, which switches off in some androids like HTC Tattoo when it sleeps, even CPU wake lock won't work, you need to hold partial or full wake lock. Can some experience guy put some light on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no solution for this programatically. You need to toggle the network option which normally cannot be done without user intervention.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way Android networking and security work, there's no way to toggle 2G/3G-4G without going into settings.  Some "rooted" phones were once able to do this, but that was disabled in 2.1 and higher.